# Why is an incorrect Stack Overflow reputation shown on other sites such as Programmers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, linked-accounts

Currently, my reputation on Stack Overflow is 448 as shown in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879153/personalnexus) and also the accounts tab on [my Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/471384/personalnexus?tab=accounts). Looking at the accounts overview on the summary tab on [my Programmers profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40190/personalnexus), however, I see a Stack Overflow reputation of 460. Note that [accounts tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40190/personalnexus?tab=accounts) does show 460, though.

Why this discrepancy?

I thought it might be a caching issue, so I waited a while, but the difference has been there for days now.

I also tried to recalculate my reputation, to see if it changed anything. It resulted in me losing 12 reputation, but the discrepancy remained. Actually, before the recalculation I had 460 on Stack Overflow and it showed up as 445 on Programmers. Immediately after the recalculation, the original 460 started being shown on Programmers (as you see it now) and on Stack Overflow I saw my actual reputation of 448 as adjusted by the recalculation.

**Update 1:** According to Anna Lear's comment below, she sees the correct Stack Overflow reputation of 448 in the accounts overview on the summary tab of [my Programmers profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40190/personalnexus). Is this maybe a location-based problem? I am located in Germany. Maybe the content delivery network node (if a CDN is used for this I'm not sure) for this region has outdated data? What do other people see from what regions?

**Update 2:** At least [one other person](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/812386#812386) sees the incorrect reputation on my profile page too. However, I'll give it a few more days, in case it is indeed a caching issue.

Comment: At a guess I would say this is a result of caching and should resolve itself after a while.

Comment: It's showing 448 on Programmers as well, so all signs point to caching as Oded suggested.

Comment: @AnnaLear This is strange because even after clearing my browser cache and even on a different machine I still see 460 on my Programmers profile (can't include a screenshot here for proof unfortunately). Hence, as far as I am concerned the issue isn't resolved.

Comment: @PersonalNexus I see 448... Not sure what to tell you, but I'll reopen this post.

Comment: @AnnaLear Strange. Maybe it depends from where in world one accesses the site, i.e. maybe here in Germany I am getting this information served from a different node in the content delivery network that has inconsistent data? I'll update the question accordingly and maybe ask around in chat for what people see from what region.

Comment: @AnnaLear Maybe I should clarify: I was looking at the summary page on my Programmers profile, not the [accounts tab](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/40190/personalnexus?tab=accounts). Because on the latter I do see 448 as well. Only the summary shows 460 for me.

Comment: @PersonalNexus Alas, no repro on the summary page on my end either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the system that updates these was down for a bit, so *some* profiles will be out of date.

This will resolve itself eventually; for the time being, the correct reputation is shown on your [accounts page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40190/personalnexus?tab=accounts) and [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/471384/personalnexus?tab=accounts).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning http://stackoverflow.com/reputation recalc?

Comment: @Truth Already did that. See the fourth paragraph in my original question.

Comment: Yes, this was it. After the [aggregator backfill](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118198) from a few minutes ago, I now see the correct reputation on all my profiles.